# External stylesheet stops Google Map from displaying

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wrote the following code:

map.js

```
function initialize(){
// Instantiate a directions service.    
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();    
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
//var greece = new google.maps.LatLng(38.4920058,  22.9803685);

var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 38.4920058, lng: 22.9803685 },
    zoom: 5,
panControl: false,
streetViewControl: false,
zoomControl: false
};

var autoCompleteOptions = {
   types: ['geocode'],
   componentRestrictions: {country: 'GR'}
};    

var rendererOptions = {
    map: map
}

// Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.   
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);     
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), mapOptions);           
autoCompleteFromDestination=newgoogle.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('fromDestination'),autoCompleteOptions); 
autoCompleteToDestination=new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('toDestination'),autoCompleteOptions);

// Instantiate an info window to hold step text.       
 stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and an html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html>

 <head>
<style type="text/css">
/* #mapCanvas{ 
position:relative;
top:60px;
width: 80%;
left: 10px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0;
    border:solid 1px #CCCCCC;   
} */
</style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/default1.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/map.js" ></script>
<title><?php echo $PageTitle; ?></title> 


 </head>
 <body>

<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the default1.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin:0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
@media print {
body {
/*
background: #ffffff url(../images/vbox_gradient.png) repeat-x 0 top;
background: #dce9f7 url(../images/body_bg.png) repeat-x 0 top;
background:url(../images/vbox_gradient.png);
*/ 
background-repeat:repeat-x;
margin:0px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
}

html,body{
height:100%;
}
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
line-height: 1;
}
body p{ 
margin:1px;
font-size:12px;
line-height:15px; /* Θέτει το ύψος γραμμής στα 15px. */
font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
padding-bottom:4px;
line-height:110%; /* Θέτει το ύψος γραμμής στο 100% του τρέχον font size. */
text-align:left;
}
p.center {
text-align:center; 
}
.redtext {
color:red;
text-align:center; 
}  
.forms{
width: 500px;
height:100%;
position:relative;
left:80px;
margin-left:2px;
margin-right:2px;
}
img {
border:none;
max-width:100%; /* ορίζει το max-width του img element σε % του containing         block. */
max-height:100%; /* ορίζει το max-height του img element σε % του containing block. */
}
table {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
border:none;
table-layout:auto; /* thetei to table-layout algorithm gia xr;hsh se ena table
auto: default timh : to width ths colonas thetete sto pio platy periex;omeno poy den spaei sthn epomenh grammh
sta kelia, einai argo afoy xreiazetai na diabasei tom periexomeno ston pinaka prin orisei to teliko layout
*/
}
td {
font-size:12px;
vertical-align:top;  /* alignment of the content of a cell */
border:none; 
}
td.vmiddle {
vertical-align:middle;
}
div {
font-size:12px;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"],  input[type="file"] {
font-size:12px;
}
textarea {
font-size:12px;
}
input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], input[type="reset"] {
font-size:12px;
background-color:#FBE904;
border:1px solid black; /* border width = 1px se oles tis pleyres     (pano,kato,dejia,aristera)
to border-style = solid (required)
to border-color=black.  (koita shorthand property toy border)
*/ 
}
select, option {
font-size:12px;
}
label {
font-weight:bold;
text-align:right;
float:right;
padding-right:4px;
}
div.error_div {
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#C00000;
padding:2px 2px 2px 2px; /* se oles tiw pleyres exo padding 2px */
border:1px solid #C00000;
background-color:yellow;
margin-left:auto; /* o browser ypologizei ena left margin */
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:4px;
margin-bottom:4px;
}
div.info_div {
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
border:1px solid #000000;
background:url('/images/fon_but.gif');
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:4px;
margin-bottom:4px;
}
.info_div {
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#000000;
padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:1px;
margin-bottom:1px;    
}
p.file_catalog_title {
background:url(/images/m3.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display:block; 
width:440px;
line-height:28px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px; 
}
p.info_text {
color:#0000C0;
padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
p.error_text {
color:#CC0000;
padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
p.small_text {
font-size:12px;
}
li.articleItem {
list-style-image:url('../images/li_bullet.gif'); /*antikathista to list type    (circle,disk) me mia image */
list-style-position:outside; /* kathorizei an tha emfanistei mesa h ejo apo to   periexomeno toy list-style-position
                         */
}
li.eventItem {
list-style-image:url('../images/li_cal.gif');
list-style-position:outside;
}
li.fileItem1 {
list-style-image:url('../images/li_file.gif');
list-style-position:outside;
}
li.fileItem2 {
list-style-image:url('../images/li_file2.gif');
list-style-position:outside;
}
li.user_other {
list-style-image:url('../images/user_other.png');
list-style-position:outside;
}
li.user_normal {
list-style-image:url('../images/user_orange.png');
list-style-position:outside;
}
li.user_author {
list-style-image:url('../images/user_green.png');
 list-style-position:outside;
}
li.user_administrator {
list-style-image:url('../images/user_suit.png');
list-style-position:outside;
}
p.byauthor {
font-size:12px;
font-style:italic; 
}
p.keywords {
font-size:12px;
font-style:italic;
color:#A0A0A0;
}
p.summary {
font-size:12px;
font-style:italic;
}
p.articleTitle {
font-size:12px;
text-align:left;
}
 p.articleSummary {
font-size:12px;
text-align:justify;
}
span.small_gray_text {
font-size:12px;
color:gray;
}
img.mini_image {
width:96px;
height:96px;
border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
float:left;
clear:right; /*katharizei to periexomeno apo adjacent images */
margin-top:4px;
margin-bottom:4px;
margin-left:4px;
margin-right:4px;
}
 /* -----------------------  DIVs ---------------------------------- */
#container{
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}
  #ActivePage {
  background-color:#03F;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;    
  margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  /*
  background:url(../images/vbox_gradient.png);
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
   */
  } 
 #header{
 padding:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
 height:124px;
 background: #ffffff url(../images/vbox_gradient.png) repeat-x 0 top;   
 clear:both; 
 }
  #body{
  padding:10px;
  padding-bottom:60px;
  }
  #PageFooter{
  position:relative;
   bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  top:10px;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  line-height:12px;
  clear:both; 
  background:url(../images/vbox_gradient_footer.png);
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  }
  #PageFooter p {
  color:#000000;
  font-size:9px;
   line-height:18px;
   text-align:center;
   }
   #PageFooter a {
   color:#000000;
   }
   #PageHeader {
   position:relative;
   width:1220px;
   height:90px;     
   /*  background:url(../images/fontop1.png);  */  
   /* vertical-align:middle; /* topotheteitai sto middle toy parent element      */

  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding-bottom:5px;     
  }
  #PageHeader td{
  font-variant:small-caps;
  font-stretch:expanded;
  font-size:40px;  
  }
  #PageMenus {
  width:1220px;   
  height:20px;     
  color:#FFFF00;
   line-height:16px;
  font-size:12px;
   font-weight:bold;
   /* vertical-align:middle;*/
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto ;
  /*background-color:#C7DDFE;*/
 }
   #PageMenus p {
   color:#FFFF00;
     line-height:16px;
   background:url(../images/fonbut.png);
     font-size:12px;
     font-weight:bold;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
   vertical-align:middle;
  }
  #PageMenus a {
   color:#FFF;
   font-weight:bold;
   display:inline-block; /* display : inline => default display , display an element as an inline element (span)
                     display : block  => display an element as a block element (like p)
                     display : inline-block => display an element as an inline-level block container.
                     the inside of this block is formatted as block-level box, and the element itself
                     is formatted as an inline-level box. */
   padding-left:3px;
   padding-right:3px;
   padding-bottom:0px;
   margin-bottom:2px;
   margin-left:2px;
   margin-right:2px;
   border:1px solid #6186AF;
   text-decoration:none; /* an einai underline, strikethrough, bling to text    */
   vertical-align:middle;
    }
   #PageMenus a:hover {
   color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#A0B3DE;
   border:1px solid #C8B3F4;
   }
   #PageMainRegion {
   /* width:770px; */
   width:1220px;
   height:60%;
   position:relative;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   top: -18px;
   }
   #PageLeftColumn {
  /* width:152px; */
  width: 220px;  
  float:left;
  clear:none;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border:none;        
 vertical-align:top;
 } 
 div#LeftMenuSelections, div#LeftMenuSelections p{
 line-height:20px;
 }
 div#LeftMenuSelections a{
 display:block;
 font-size:14px;
 clear:both;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin:0px;
 color:#000000;
 padding-left:4px;
 padding-right:2px;
 padding-top:0px;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 border:1px solid #CCCCCC;   
  }
 div#LeftMenuSelections a:hover{
 text-decoration:none;
 border:1px solid #A0A0A0;
 background-color:#FBE904;
 }
 div#LeftMenuSelectionsPlus{
  border:1px solid #CCCCCC;  
   background:url(../images/fon.gif);
  position:relative; /* thetei to element se position relative to its normal      position,
  etsi left:20 prs8etei 20px sto elementsLEFT position */
   top:0px; right:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px; 
  }
  #instructions {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  margin-top:5px;
   border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
  position:relative;
  top:2px; right:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px;
  text-align:left;
  }
  #instructions p{ 
   background:url(../images/fon.gif);      
  }
  #navigatePanel{
  position:relative;
  top:30px;
  border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
   margin: 0;
  padding:0;    
   }
  #PageCenterColumn {
  width:1000px;
  height: 100%;
   position:relative;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  display:inline-block;
  left:0px;
  border:thick;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
  #PageRightColumn {
  width:180px;
  height:100%;
  float:right;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  clear:right;     
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align:top;
  overflow:hidden;
   }
  div#RightMenuSelections, div#RightMenuSelections p{
  background:url(../images/fon.gif);
  text-align:center;
  line-height:18px;
  font-size:12px;
  }
  div#RightMenuSelectionsPlus{
  border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
  }
  div#RightMenuSelections a{
  display:block;
  clear:both;
   text-decoration:none;
  margin:0px;
  color:#000000;
   padding-left:0px;
   padding-right:0px;
   padding-top:0px;
   padding-bottom:0px;
   border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
  }
   #mapCanvas{ 
  position:relative;
  top:60px;
  width: 80%;
  left: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  border:solid 1px #CCCCCC;   
  }
  #crimeCanvas{
  position:relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border:solid 1px #CCCCCC;
  }
   #formLogin{
     top:450px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #FBE904;  
    }
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)  {
    body {
   margin:0px;
   padding-top:0px;
   padding-bottom:0px;
   padding-left:5px;
   padding-right:5px;
   background: #ffffff;
           /*
   background: #dce9f7 url(../images/body_bg.png) repeat-x 0 top;
   background:url(../images/vbox_gradient.png);
           */
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   }
    #header{
     width:1235px;
     }
    #PageHeader{
    width:1220px;
    }
    #PageFooter{
    width:1220px;
    }
   }

 /* -----------------------  DIVs ---------------------------------- */
```

The issue is that when I use the rel stylesheet the map does not display.
When I uncomment the content in style tag and delete rel stylesheet the map displayed.
Any suggestion?

Comment: You might have an issue inside you `default1.css`.

Comment: As you've not shown us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or even the content of `default1.css` this is more-or-less unanswerable (except perhaps a lucky guess).

Comment: I'm pretty sure your map will never be displayed, there are also JS-issues(you've included the maps-API multiple times and inside `initialize` you access `map` before it has been set ). However, when you fix the JS-issues and append the rules of the style-tag to the external css the map should be drawn(so the css-issue is that you didn't define a height for `#mapCanvas` in `default1.css`)